# Do Element.scrollHeight and Element.scrollTop calculate the return value everytime they get called?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I've implemented my own scrollable layout, and I've defined some fields in it storing `Element.scrollHeight`, `Element.scrollTop`, `Element.scrollWidth` and `Element.scrollLeft` to avoid possible duplicate calculations(it seems the techincal term for this is `reflow`) as they are used in several custom life cycle methods.

I'm wondering if this is redundant in thought that those properties might be just defined as getter to protect them from being changed by clients, and the getters would just return invisible fields from clients storing actual values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

I don't know if this source is reliable but it says yes they trigger reflow.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of both.

These properties [among others](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) need the layout box to be up to date to return the correct value, so yes they will trigger a reflow ... if necessary.

If the layout is up to date though, the browser doesn't need to recalculate it, and no reflow will get triggered, they can just pick the internal value requested from the last layout box calculations.

So calling these several times is not a problem if nothing did change the layout in between these calls. However if something does change the layout in between (like class change, DOM node insertion, etc.), each call might cost a lot, so call these carefully.

---

Ps: regarding the getter thing, it's not at all to prevent the user from setting these, since you can actually set these:

```js
console.log( div.offsetWidth );
Object.defineProperty( div, "offsetWidth", { value: 0 } );
console.log( div.offsetWidth );
```

```html
<div id="div">hello</div>
```